# can't color area below logarithm curve

Tags: r, plot

I'm using the polygon function to color the area below different curves, but when I try

```
plot(1:100, -log(1:100), type="l")
polygon(1:100, -log(1:100),col="grey70" )
```

the function colors the area above the curve, not below, some one knows how to inform the function the right polygon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because polygon joins the ended point. Try this :

```
plot(1:100, -log(1:100), type="l")
polygon(c(1:100,1), c(-log(1:100),-log(100)),col="grey70")
```

HTH